# get specific key data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm converting XML file into associative array to pull out the data, the problem is that I have to make 10 loops depends on arrays number in order to get the data.

Is there a better way to get a specific column data without creating many loops? because I want to assign them to variables.

The array I'm trying to get data from

```
Array
(
  [catalog] => Array
  (
    [comp] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [look] => Array
        (
          [shp] => Array
          (
            [wok] => Array
            (
              [group] => Array
              (
                [customer] => Array
                (
                  [author] => jack
                  [title] => Midnight Rain1
                  [genre] => Fantasy
                  [price] => 5.95
                  [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                  [description] => A former architect battles corporate zombies.
                )
                [customer2] => Array
                (
                  [author] => lemass
                  [title] => Midnight Rain1
                  [genre] => Fantasy
                  [price] => 5.95
                  [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                  [description] => A former architect battles corporate zombies.
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
      [1] => Array
      (
        [look] => Array
        (
          [shp] => Array
          (
            [wok] => Array
            (
              [group] => Array
              (
                [customer] => Array
                (
                  [author] => jon
                  [title] => Midnight Rain1
                  [genre] => Fantasy
                  [price] => 5.95
                  [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                  [description] => A former architect battles corporate zombies.
                )
                [customer2] => Array
                (
                  [author] => kirito
                  [title] => Midnight Rain1
                  [genre] => Fantasy
                  [price] => 5.95
                  [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                  [description] => A former architect battles corporate zombies.
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I'm trying to get the data like this.

I have 2 arrays `customer` and `customer1`

I want to get the data like this

`customer => author`

Output

```
jack
jon
```

Because they are in the `customer` array

Is it possible?

Comment: your missing the first 2 levels

Comment: In fact, when you loop (foreach), you **are on the 'Shp2' index** :)
`foreach( $arr as $index => $comp ) { echo $index, ' => ', var_dump($comp); }` and you will see

Answer (score 1):

```
 $comps = $arr['Shp']['test'];
 foreach ($comps  as $comp) {
 if (is_array($comp))
 echo $comp['Shp2'] ['customer'] ['address'] ['ad1']; } 
 or use this echo $comp['test'] ['Shp2'] ['customer'] ['address'] ['ad1'];
```

Comment: @jack Mention not:-)

Comment: same error appeared again can you help me please! I adjusted the answer!